# SSHFS mount from fstab fails to authenticate

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, fstab, sshfs

I created SSH key and transferred it to my target device using *ssh-copy-id* and now I can `ssh targetUsername@targetHost -p 8798` without providing RSA key nor password for *targetUsername@targetHost* however when I try to mount SSHFS share in *fstab* (ending is for [debug purposes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS#fstab_mounting_issues))

`sshfs#targetUsername@targetHost:/mnt /media/omnia2 fuse.sshfs _netdev,defaults,IdentityFile=/home/localUsername/.ssh/id_rsa,idmap=user,port=8798,ssh_command=ssh\040-vv,sshfs_debug,debug 0 0`

the password for *targetUsername@targetHost* is demanded and rejected `Permission denied, please try again` even though I provide a good one. What surprises me is how the RSA key authentication is dropped:

```
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/localUsername/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
sshfs#targetUsername@targetHost's password:
```

I think I have all local permissions clear. My other attempt was to use `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` for key storage yet that did not change a thing.

Comment: Check the logs on the server to find out why.

Comment: Thank you, `we did not send a packet` was so unclear to me that I wouldn't have thought that there actually was an authentication attempt and I will find anything useful in the target's logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking `journalctl -u ssh.service` at the target machine I realised that target host recognised `sshfs#targetUsername` from fstab entry as a username while my intention was to log into *targetUsername*. Removing `sshfs#` from fstab entry resolved the problem.